# Declare variable in if and use outside

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var factory = function(someCondition) {
    var para1 = 'some value';
    if(someCondition)
        var para2 = 'some other value';

    return new MyClass(para1, para2);
}
```

I know that this code is [perfectly legal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), even though `para2` is declared inside the `if` but used outside.

My question is: Is this - although legal - considered bad style by major Javascript style guides? If so, by which and what are the proposed alternatives?

Just to be clear: I know about hoisting and the fact that variables are not block scoped but function scoped.

Comment: About the close vote: I rephrased it. It no longer is based on your opinion.

Comment: I saw that and retracted my vote. Good job.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Thanks for helping me make my question better :)

Comment: I dug around a little, and it looks like [JSCS](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jscs), a highly configurable checker that comes with presets like Crockford, Google or jQuery styles, does not support such a rule. Therefore, chances are major style guides do not actually care about this rule (yet).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Thanks. Want to post this as an answer?

Comment: Not really, that's still speculation on my part (I do have a hard time stating "no" or "they don't care" in answers ;)

Comment: I would suggest to use ternary operator instead: `var para2 = someCondition? 'some other value' : '';`

Answer (score 5):

Technically the variable is *"hoisted"*, the code will execute like this:

```
var para1 = 'some value';
var para2;
if(someCondition)
    para2 = 'some other value';
```

All `var` declarations inside a scope declare variables in this scope before code is executed. As such, it doesn't make much of a difference in practice. However, I'd consider it good style to write the code explicitly as above to make it obvious what variables exist in the scope. "Hiding" variable declarations inside conditions can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 3):

That should not be a bad style, this could be a bit confusing.

Any way javascript will do it like bellow because of **hoisting**, So better write also like bellow.

```
var factory = function(someCondition) {
    var para1 = 'some value';
    var para2; //declare it here
    if(someCondition)
        para2 = 'some other value'; //assign the value here

    return new MyClass(para1, para2);
}
```

The ES6 version introducing a new keyword **let** which gives variables **block scoping.**

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: why this is not bad design, & I think this is alternative also.

Comment: It is an alternative, alright, but you didn't answer the part whether my version is considered bad style.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth sorry answering the question, I don't think that is a bad style, but it could be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

An example of JavaScript 'hoisting':

```
var para2 = "my value";

var factory = function(someCondition) {
    var para1 = 'some value';
    console.log(para2);
    if(someCondition)
        var para2 = 'some other value';

    return new MyClass(para1, para2);
}

factory(true); // undefined
```

Above code will log 'undefined'.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. It would log exactly the same as if you would have declared `var para2;` before you call `log`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Some people may think and get confuse that it will show "my value" (global) as variable is not defined. but, in javascript all the variable are defined at start of function.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses function scope, hence I would write it like this

```
var factory = function(someCondition) {
    var para1 = 'some value';
    var para2 = 'some other value';
    if(someCondition)
    {
        // some code..
    }

    return new MyClass(para1, para2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's all right.

```
 var factory = function(someCondition) {
    var para1 = 'some value';
    if(someCondition){
       var para2 = 'some other value';
       alert(para2);
    }

    alert(para2);
    return new MyClass(para1, para2);
 }
```

I have added alert so that you can focus on. Here. inside the if statement, you declare a variable called para2. When this code is run, the alert function directly below it displays 'some other value'!. That makes sense. What might make less sense is that the second alert that is outside of the if statement also displays 'some other value'!.

Here is what is going on. Your para2 variable is declared inside if what is known as a block. A block is anything that appears within the open and close brackets - { and }. In many programming languages, variables declared inside a block are part of that block's own scope. That means those variables are local and can't be accessed outside of the block.

JavaScript is not like those many "other" programming languages. JavaScript doesn't support block scoping.

See more [here](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/variable_scope_js.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You might notice that I linked an explanation to exactly this concept in my question. In other words, I am aware of this.